# Is there a way to find the time elapsed from a datetime column in a dataframe based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, if-statement

I have a data frame called actions. The columns are user_id, action_timestamp and action. The users are students who perform an action at a specific time given by the action_timestamp.

Which student has spent the longest uninterrupted session? (here a “session” is defined as a length of time where a student performs a series of actions with less than 10 minutes in between them; the “session” stop when the next action in the series has been performed 10 minutes or more after the last one, after which a new “session” starts)[image: subset of df]

The code I am trying:

```
new['diff']= new['action_timestamp'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')

for i in new['diff']:
    if not np.isnan:
        if (i <=10.0):
            new['session']= 1.0
        else:
            new['session']=0.0

new.loc[new['diff'] <= 10.0, 'session'] = 1.0 
new.loc[new['diff'] > 10.0, 'session'] = 0.0
```

This does not prove to be the right answer. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you start by grouping the `user_id` first?

Comment: Yes, thats right, bafter grouping should I try to find the difference in time-lapsed? I am not sure what to do after grouping.

Comment: You need to provide sample data in text and also your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `np.where`:

```
new['diff'] = new['action_timestamp'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
new['session'] = np.where(new['diff'].gt(10), 0, 1)
```

Comment: This yeilds a new column, but the 'diff' column is not right. Could you let me know how I can group the user_id and then use the difference in the time.